# C# why is it skipping my console.readline()?

Tags: c#, readline, skip

So the program is working correctly, but for some reason, on the second time through, it is skipping the Console.ReadLine() prompt altogether. I ran through debug and confirmed that it isn't a loop problem as it is actually entering the method, displaying the WriteLine then completely skipping over the ReadLine, thus returning a blank back to Main() causing it to exit. What the deuce? Any ideas?

here is the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace LAB4B
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string inString;
            ArrayList translatedPhrase = new ArrayList();

            DisplayInfo();
            GetInput(out inString);

            do
            {
                GetTranslation(inString, translatedPhrase);
                DisplayResults(inString, translatedPhrase);
                GetInput(out inString);
            } while (inString != "");

        }

        static void DisplayInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("*** You will be prompted to enter a string of  ***");
            Console.WriteLine("*** words. The string will be converted into ***");
            Console.WriteLine("*** Pig Latin and the results displayed. ***");
            Console.WriteLine("*** Enter as many strings as you would like. ***");
        }

        static void GetInput(out string words)
        {

            Console.Write("\n\nEnter a group of words or ENTER to quit: ");
            words = Console.ReadLine();            
        }

        static void GetTranslation(string originalPhrase, ArrayList translatedPhrase)
        {
            int wordLength;                       
            string[] splitPhrase = originalPhrase.Split();

            foreach (string word in splitPhrase)
            {
                wordLength = word.Length;
                translatedPhrase.Add(word.Substring(1, wordLength - 1) + word.Substring(0, 1) + "ay");
            }          




        }

        static void DisplayResults(string originalString, ArrayList translatedString)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nOriginal words: {0}", originalString);
            Console.Write("New Words: ");
            foreach (string word in translatedString)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", word);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

It's because of your `Console.Read()` call in `DisplayResults` method. It generally reads just one character. If you press ENTER (which is actually combination of 2 characters - carriage return and line feed) on `Console.Read()` it only gets carriage return character, and line feed gets to your next console reading method - `Console.ReadLine()` in `GetInput()` method. Since line feed character is also a linux ENTER character, `Console.ReadLine()` reads it as one line.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the `Console.Read()` in your `DisplayResults` method to `Console.ReadLine()`. That seems to make everything behave as it should.

Comment: Oh wow. I didnt realize that Read() would affect ReadLine() as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You said the second time round. Looking at your do-while loop, That would fall through because your variable *inString* is initialised and not empty.

Btw, usually safer to use

```
do
{
} while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(inString));
```

than to directly compare to an empty string.