# System.FormatException in C#

Tags: c#, formatexception

I keep getting a FormatException in each of the cases on the line where I try to assign the value for the sale variable. Anyone know what I am doing wrong? I am supposed to make this console program as homework to learn about loops, but I am finding out more about other things. It is supposed to keep a running tab of salesperson's commission based a a 10% commission of each sale. Anyways, here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TubSales
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         char initial;
         const double COMM_INT = 0.10;
         double sale, aComm = 0, bComm = 0, eComm = 0;
         Console.Write("Enter 'A' for Andrea, 'B' for Brittany,\n'E' for Eric, or 'Z' to quit >> ");
         initial = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
         while (initial != 'z' && initial != 'Z')
         {
            switch (initial)
            {
               case 'a':
               case 'A':
                  Console.Write("Enter the sales for Andrea >> ");
                  sale = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                  aComm = aComm + COMM_INT * sale;
                  break;
               case 'b':
               case 'B':
                  Console.Write("Enter the sales for Brittany >> ");
                  sale = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                  bComm = bComm + COMM_INT * sale;
                  break;
               case 'e':
               case 'E':
                  Console.Write("Enter the sales for Eric >> ");
                  sale = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                  eComm = eComm + COMM_INT * sale;
                  break;
               default:
                  Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a valid initial");
                  break;
            }
            Console.Write("Enter 'A' for Andrea, 'B' for Brittany, or 'E' for Eric >> ");
            initial = (char)Console.Read();
         }
         Console.WriteLine("Andrea had {0}, Brittany had {1}, and Eric had {2} in commissions.", aComm.ToString("C"), bComm.ToString("C"), eComm.ToString("C"));
         Console.Write("Press any key to exit... ");
         Console.ReadKey();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Reed's answers is great, it's not the problem here.

What really happens is the same situation as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800343/c-sharp-why-is-it-skipping-my-console-readline)

Console.Read only read the "Second part of the carriage return" and returns "". This is why the Convert fails.

replace

```
initial = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
```

with

```
initial = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 5):

> I keep getting a FormatException in each of the cases on the line where I try to assign the value for the sale variable. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

The [Convert.ToDouble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k.aspx) method will raise a `FormatException` if the string (returned from `Console.ReadLine()`) is not a valid number.

Typically, if you want to parse user input, it's a better idea to use [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx) instead, as this lets you determine whether the input was a valid number *without* catching the exception.

This would normally look something like:

```
Console.Write("Enter the sales for Andrea >> ");
while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out sale))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Value entered was not a valid number.");
    Console.Write("Enter the sales for Andrea >> ");
}
// Once you get here, "sale" will be set appropriately
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
initial = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
```

with

```
initial = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine().FirstOrDefault());
```