# Console.ReadLine() skips the first input character

Tags: c#

```
Console.WriteLine("You have not installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2, do you want to install it now? (Y/N): ");
//var answerKey = Console.ReadKey();
//var answer = answerKey.Key;
var answer = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("After key pressed.");
Console.WriteLine("Before checking the pressed key.");

//if(answer == ConsoleKey.N || answer != ConsoleKey.Y)
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(answer) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(answer.Trim()) || string.Compare(answer.Trim(), "N", true) == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The installation can not proceed.");
    Console.Read();
    return;
}
```

I have tried to input these:

- y -> it gives me an empty string,
- y(whitespace+y) -> it gives me the "y"

I have checked other similar posts, but none of them solves my problem.
The ReadLine() still skips the 1st input character.

**UPDATE** Solved, [see below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16313759/1336654).

Comment: Please check out this post. It will explain your problem 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800343/c-sharp-why-is-it-skipping-my-console-readline

Comment: I tried this at Ideone.com and had no problems (http://ideone.com/1MSBMb). What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Note for other readers: from @Franva's answer below, it seems that the question is incomplete...

Comment: @DanPuzey Hi Dan, please point out what part this question misses, thx

Comment: @Franva: you hadn't explained that you were running the code in a separate thread, which would have been the obvious culprit.  Answering without that knowledge would never have given you anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for replying my post.

It's my bad that not taking consideration of the multi-thread feature in my code. I will try to explain where I was wrong in order to say thank you to all your replies.

```
BackgroundWorker worker = .....;
  public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InitWorker();
        Console.Read();
    }

public static void InitWorker()
{
    ....
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}


static void worker_DoWork(....)
{
  .....this is where I wrote the code...
}
```

The problem was I started a sub-thread which runs asynchronously with the host thread. When the sub-thread ran to this line : var answer = Console.ReadLine();
the host thread ran to the Console.Read(); at the same time.
So what happened was it looked like I was inputting a character for var answer = Console.ReadLine();, but it actually fed to the Console.Read() which was running on the host thread and then it's the turn for the sub-thread to ReadLine(). When the sub-thread got the input from keyboard, the 1st inputted character had already been taken by the host thread and then the whole program finished and closed.

I hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: Makes sense now. You can use `Application.Run()` to prevent exit at the end of your main, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested change:

```
Console.Write("Enter some text: ");
String response = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("You entered: " + response + ".");
```

Key points:

1) A string is probably the easiest type of console input to handle

2) Console input is line oriented - you must type "Enter" before the input becomes available to the program.

Comment: How is this different from what was posted?  All you've done is explicitly type the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to change Console.Read --> Console.ReadLine

Comment: I also compiled your code and tested it, I get the same value as i entered, also I'm using Mono on my Linux box.

Comment: Glad it worked out. I was getting a little worried wondering why your original code would work. Yah Good'ol Threading :)